# How to handle touch events for cocos?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js

Is it possible to handle touch enter or touch leave in cocos creator 1.9?
I don't find any.
i tried to do it with touch move but it doesn't worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle node input touch cocos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210423/how-to-handle-node-input-touch-cocos)

Comment: is this different from the question you asked two hours earlier ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register callback for touch event.
Read manual [here](http://docs.cocos.com/creator/manual/en/scripting/events.html#listen-to-events) first.
In the sample code:

```
onLoad: function () {
this.node.on('mousedown', function ( event ) {
  console.log('Hello!');
});}
```

Use `cc.Node.EventType.TOUCH_START` for touch enter (`TOUCH_MOVE` / `TOUCH_END` / `TOUCH_CANCEL` for other purpose) instead of `'mousedown'`;